# What is the notation $\delta$ here?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm reading the book "Introduction to Lie Algebra and Representation Theory - J. E. Humphrey", I have a question on an example on the page number $2$. That is

> **Example:** For reference, we write down the multiplication table for $gl(n, F)$
>   relative to the standard basis consisting of the matrices $e_{ij}$
>   (having $1$ in the $(i, j)$ position and $0$ elsewhere). Since $e_{ij} e_{kl} = \delta_{jk} e_{il}$ it follows that: 
>   $$[e_{ij}, e_{kl}] = \delta_{jk} e_{il} - \delta_{li} e_{kj}.$$ 
>   Notice that the
>   coefficients are all $1,-1$ or $0$; in particular, all of them lie in
>   the prime field of $F$.

**My question:** What is the meaning of the notation $\delta$ here?

Comment: Probably the [kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) $\delta_{i,j} := \begin{cases} 0, & \text{if } i \neq j , \\ 1, & \text{else.} \end{cases}$.

Comment: Could you show that more implicitly? I’m starting to study Lie algebra at today’s morning.

Comment: Minh, you should write down the $4$-dimensional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_2(F)$ explicitly yourself (not implicitly, but explicitly). The vector space has a basis $\{e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22}\}$. The bracket is given by $[A,B]=AB-BA$ for these matrices $e_{ij}$.

Comment: It's definitely the Kronecker delta.  @Minh you will have to be more specific if you have another question, because your first question was answered.